# Sharing React project with others

Tags: react-native, expo

So me and my friends are working on a project using React Native and the Expo CLI. Now I know there is an option to publish the app, but is there a way to send the project file and have it edited in real time? Uploading it to google drive every time one of us changes a small line of code is a pretty big hassle. Is there some way, where it automatically gets updated every time we edit it?

Thanks.

P.S: If there isn't any way to do so, could you suggest some relatively easy way to collaborate?

Comment: Are you not using any kind of SCM tools like `git` ??

Answer (score 1):

- [VS Code Live Share Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack)
- [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/)
- [codeCollab](https://codecollab.io/#Welcome)

The most appropriate would be VS code Live share Extension.